# Referenced column has to be a primary key column on the target entity doctrine - Symfony2

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having a few issues when trying to validate my database schema, insofar as I get conflicting error messages: when I do what it says, it tells me it's wrong and vice versa.

Here is my setup:

I have two tables which are relevant in this issue, one called order_option and order_product. There is no direct mapping between them as this is an OpenCart installation so that's handled at that end but when I try to validate the schema it fails with the following message:

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\Oc49OrderOption'
>   mapping is invalid:
>   * The referenced column name 'order_id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'AppBundle\Entity\Oc49OrderProduct'.

The current Entity layout for the order_option table:

```
/**
 * Oc49OrderOption
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="oc49_order_option")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Oc49OrderOption
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $orderId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_product_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $orderProductId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_option_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $productOptionId;

etc ...
```

If I alter it so it reads like this:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
*/
private $orderId
```

when I run the validation check again I get the following message:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]   Single id is not allowed on
>   composite primary key in entity AppBundle\Entity\Oc49OrderOption

So it is almost like if I try to correct the first error, it tells me that it's not allowed - kind of like a catch 22!

Any ideas? This is the only problem with the schema as I've so far managed to fix all other conflicts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your primary key 2 columns in your database?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing a bit of a re-jig with the database, turned out there were some other unnecessary mappings lying around, so I cleaned them up and the error hasn't re-occurred.

Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 */
private $orderId;
```